# C++ project doesn't compile with makefiles in different folders in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I have a C++ project, with all the source codes and the makefile in the project folder that, compiles fine in Eclipse. I put my source codes in a folder named library and, as I read in the eclipse guide page, I changed the path in :*Project>>properties*, I unchecked *use default build command* and in *Build command*I gave the path to the makefile that lives in the library folder now (see attached image : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Ezn.png)). When I build the project I have "no rule to make the target "libImageFormats.c" necessary for "libImageFormats.o", stop" error (see attached image : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDSV7.png)) and I don't know how to fix it. Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work even when I give the path of the makefile in the new folder ? And in case in the same project we have two folders with a makefile in each one, how can the project be built ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Sincerely,

-J

PS: I don't know why when I write "Hello everyone" it doesn't show ? Weird !

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. On this site we focus on the question and answer and thus skip the "hello" part. 
As for your issue I'd recommend to put the path to the Makefile in the field `Build directory` and to keep the default build command ( `make` ). You can use the Eclipse variables to do so. Here you can try with `${ProjDirPath}/library`

Comment: oh that's great it worked thank you so much @TimF :-). And if I add another folder, let's name it Folder2, with a another makefile in it, is it possible to add another building directory ?

Thanks again.
-J

Comment: Not that I know, in this case you're supposed to have a top-level Makefile in which you call the ones in the subfolders. Note however that this is not very efficient, it's recommended for small to medium-sized projects to only have one top-level Makefile and to manage everything in it, because that's how GNU make is the most efficient and easy to use.